# Is it possible to install qwt to Qt6?

Tags: qt, installation, qwt

I have Qt6 (6.5) built from source and I am trying to install the Qwt library according to this guide: https://qwt.sourceforge.io/qwtinstall.html

1. `/home/lparadox/Tools/qt/qt6-install/bin/qmake qwt.pro`
2. `make -j8`

and I'm getting the error:

```bash
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/lparadox/Tools/qt/qt6-install/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/lparadox/Tools/qt/qwt-6.2.0/src/src.pro ) && make -f Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lparadox/Tools/qt/qwt-6.2.0/src'
moc qwt_dyngrid_layout.h
compiling qwt_dyngrid_layout.cpp
compiling qwt_magnifier.cpp
compiling qwt_panner.cpp
compiling qwt_picker.cpp
compiling qwt_symbol.cpp
qwt_symbol.cpp:20:10: fatal error: qsvgrenderer.h: No such file or directory
   20 | #include <qsvgrenderer.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1453: obj/qwt_symbol.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lparadox/Tools/qt/qwt-6.2.0/src'
make: *** [Makefile:53: sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I see the `qsvgrenderer.h` is present. Is this problem about the Qt version ?

Comment: Make sure your .pro file has `QT += svg`.

Comment: Actually after using `qmake6` and not `qmake` from the `bin` dir the error disappeared.